# Why Python `filter` vs similar list comprehension is not returning similar results?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, file-handling

Why below two statements are not returning same lists?

```
with open("test.py") as f:
    upChars = list(filter(lambda ch : ch.isupper(), [ch for ch in f.read()]))
    upChars1 = [ch1 for ch1 in f.read() if ch1.isupper()]
    print(f"\n1:  {upChars},\n2:  {upChars1}")
```

Output :

> 1:  ['T', 'B', 'S', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'T', ...contains all uppercase chars],
>
> 2:  []

Comment: Please let me know if if I am committing any trivial/stupid logical mistake here !!

Comment: You can not read the file twice. You have to seek to its' beginning or re-open it.

Comment: worked after adding ` f.seek(0)` , Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's because you cannot read a file twice. After the first `read()`, the descriptor is at the end of file. Usually, when preforming multiple things on a file, putting it into a list makes sense:

```
test = f.read()
```

then you can use it multiple times. Try and print the result of a double read to see this in action. If you really insist, you could `f.seek(0)` to reset it, but this is more overhead than its worth.

Comment: worked after adding ` f.seek(0)` , Thanks!